# I want to fetch ID based on provided name from api which returns both. I want to store this ID which will be used in another request

Tags: jmeter, postman, beanshell

This api returns me dashboard_id and dashboard_name as highlighted in attached image. My requirement is to fetch dashboard_id based on dashboard_name using this api in jmeter? Both ID and Name are unique here. Is it possible to achieve this in jmeter?

Since we do not have any api which will return me dashboard_id based on dashboard_name. So wanted to use this current api which has both ID and Name, and based on Name I want to fetch ID, and ID will be used in different request.

Using Jmeter, I am providing user credentials and dashboard_id via 'CSV Data Set Config' that is being used in request, but too many ID's are confusing, so better we want to use dashboard_name which is more readable and add current api from where we want to fetch ID, so that ID can be used in another request.

I was trying to go though Beanshell Sampler to achieve this, but still didn't find a way to achieve it. Please suggest me a way to achieve this in jmeter?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) and the following [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query:

```
$..[?(@.name == 'New Dashboard - 6')].dashboardId
```

Full configuration:

[image]

You should be able to refer the extracted id as `${dashboardId}` where required.

Going forward please:

- [Don't post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)
- Post the code fully
- [Don't use Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as it's performance anti-pattern

Comment: Will check this one...I can use dashboard_name variable also like this?
$..[?(@.name == '${dashboard_name}')].dashboardId

Comment: Sure you can, any JMeter [Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [Variable](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) can be used in the JsonPath query

Comment: JSON Extractor is not working for me, here is the link where I tried your solution, could you please check once whether I am missing something here
(1) https://ibb.co/84pnmpZ
(2) https://ibb.co/4YqQdnj

Comment: As Dmitri suggested it is working fine, you have selected text in your result tree (which I can see in your image), you need to select `JSON Path Tester` from the dropdown. Please check details here https://chercher.tech/jmeter/json-assertion-jmeter#:~:text=In%20the%20View%20Result%20Tree%2C%20select%20the%20JSON,enter%20%24.records%20and%20then%20run%20the%20thread%20group.

Comment: @DmitriT I was doing some mistakes in verifying it.... tried it again, it is working well, thanks